# Can't run cstrike.exe file in counter strike1.6 using WINE

Tags: windows, wine, games

when i right click on cstrike file and select **open with wine windows program loader** it doesnt show any error nor the game gets started.

Comment: There are a huge number of things that could be going wrong. The first step in troubleshooting any Wine issue is to try running the app from the command line so you can see the errors that are preventing it from running.

Comment: can you please give me the command to run it through terminal ........

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `find ~/.wine -name "cstrike.exe"`, if that's the name of the executable. That should get you the path of the file. Then run `wine (path returned by previous command)`.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I am assuming the following since you did not mention it in your question:

- You are using Ubuntu 12.10 32 Bit
- You have a good CPU, Video Card and amount of memory to run Wine with CS 1.6
- You are using a Wine version that is not the latest
- You did not install but actually copy CS to your Ubuntu system or ran CS from another Driver or partition (Maybe partitioned for Windows and shared with Ubuntu)

So with all of that said, do the following:

1. Open Dash and type `terminal`, then open the terminal.
2. Type the following 3 lines:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install wine1.5
   ```
3. Open Dash again and type `winecfg` so it configures Wine for the first time.
4. Find `cstrike.exe` and double-click on it or right-click and select wine.
5. During installation, the default will take `C:\Program Files\Counter-Strike 1.6` as installation directory. Change it to any other directory which is available in your Linux file system. It would help you in next steps.

If the above does not work after executing it, install an extension for Nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
```

After that logout and login again. Now go to your CS folder and right-click in an empty space, you will now see an option that says "Open in Terminal".

[image: "Open in Terminal" option in Nautilus]

This is a quick way to get to a folder without typing too much (Easier for beginners). When the terminal opens, type `wine cstrike.exe`. This should give you the information needed to know why cstrike is not working.

A common problem is a missing DLL Library (Pretty common actually). The solution is to just copy the missing DLL to the game folder.

For example, this is the output I got with a friends CS:

```
$ wine cstrike.exe 
fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"SecDrv" failed to start: 2
err:module:import_dll Library MSVBVM60.DLL (which is needed by L"F:\\Half-Life\\cstrike.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"F:\\Half-Life\\cstrike.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

If you read through the lines you will see that it says wine had an error while trying to import the `MSVBVM60.DLL` file. Google this file and paste it in the game folder where `cstrike.exe` resides. The [DLL-files.com](https://www.dll-files.com/) is a good place to start.

After pasting it in your game folder, the game should work:

[image]

Comment: What do you do if you only get the `fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"SecDrv" failed to start: 2` bit? There is no other message for me (although its a different game... MOHAA)

Comment: @luchonacho this is my guide for that game on a previous version https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20075&iTestingId=85599 although there are others but you can see which packages were installed for me when the game was working.